# Should I fork or should I clone an organization's repository that I have push access?

Tags: git, github

Currently I'm thinking about starting my own organization on Github to work on a few projects with a group of friends. Each one of us will have full access to every repository there. But since I've never been a member of an organization on Github, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Should each member fork the repositories they're working on and then send pull requests from their forked repositories back to the upstream repositories on the organization **or** should each one of us just clone the repositories from the organization and just push commits straight to them without a pull request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trust your friends that they will not break anything too often then just push to the organization repository.

The pull request model is suited for projects where you want to do code review. That includes open-source projects, where you of course do not want everybody to be able to push into your repository. It's usual that core dev team pushes directly and other developers use pull requests.

Both approaches can be combined - even if you use pull requests for your organization repository, someone can fork it and grant push access to this fork to others so they can push to this fork directly. After they are finished they can make pull request to the "main" repository.

Comment: How to grant push access to my fork of organization repository?

Comment: @MaciejMatys I don't know, that depends how is git deployed in your organization. If you se Github or Bitbucket then go to Settings - Access Management.

Comment: We use github and private repos and I can't add anybody to my fork of organization repository. My team has only read access to organizations repos. It looks like permissions are inherited and not editable.

Comment: @MaciejMatys I don't use github private repos. Please ask a new question here on SO or contact Github support.